# Detecting an emulator using the windows api

Tags: c++, winapi, emulation

I've been given a program that emulates the Windows API. I'm trying to see what function calls this emulator changes, and what values it returns.

Instead of writing code to query various functions from the WinAPI , I'm looking for a way to automate code generation (preferably in C/C++) to query a large number of functions provided by the WinAPI . Is anything like this possible or has it been done for other projects that I could leverage?

Comment: I don't see a way to automate this process without parsing the SDK header files. While you can inspect and enumerate exports from binaries (like kernel32.dll, user32.dll, etc.) there is no way to retrieve any type information (which is not encoded in the C name mangling). And even with the type information available you can not simply pass random values. Again, I don't see a way to automate generation of those test cases. Unfortunately there is no native equivalent to [Pex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819140.aspx).

Comment: Many functions can't be used in isolation, they require arguments that were returned by other functions. Other than spitting out the name of each function, I don't think there is much that can be automated.

Comment: By "what function calls the emulator changes", do you mean dramatic changes (creating a file with a valid name doesn't work), or things like "If you call this thing, where parameter 5 is invalid, does it give the same error message as the real API?"

Comment: If the answer over at [SO.RE](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/detecting-an-emulator-using-the-windows-api) did not satisfy you, why have you accepted it? Why did you not leave any comments?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'm looking for either. Initially, I was thinking of just examining calls to query the system (such as getting the free disk space), but finding differences in error handling could be useful as well.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky, that answer gave me a way to approach it from a reversing standpoint, but I was also looking for information on how to develop code for this. I'm trying to understand the problem from both approaches to figure out which will be better.